# SQL Server 2016 CTP2.0 Evaluation

Tags: sql-server, evaluation, data-recovery

Is there a SQL Server 2016 CTP2.0 installation for evaluation in a server?

An update from SQL Server 2016 CTP2.0 was found and the system stop the service for install that update ..... but "evaluation period expired" says when start the service... and doesn't start never.

I try repair the installation, update edition for another evaluation, but nothing remove the "evaluation period expired", I can't "downgrade" to SQL Server Express, the wizard doesn't allow it.

How can I recover my database? Must install SQL Server again? Download a new version for evaluation? Get a key from some website?

What to do?

All a new development in for testing is there!

Answer (score 0):

CTP2 is really old as far as pre-release software goes. I don't believe the current available pre-release versions supports upgrading in-place from CTP2. Even if you get it to work, it is an untested upgrade path so nobody really knows what happens or doesn't happen. If you have the .mdf/.ldf files, you can try attaching it to a SQL Server 2016 RC3 instance and see if that works.